# Did the distances of the reflecting mirrors in Michelson Morley need to be precise to 100 nm or less?

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, speed-of-light, interference, diffraction

When I took Physics, both in HS and College I was taught that the reason the Michelson Morley experiment "could" produce an interference pattern at the detector location was that the two beams returning from the reflecting mirrors could be out of phase by a fraction of a wavelength.  For visible light this would be around 100 nm or less.  That's about the size of a virus.  Seems impossible that the reflecting mirrors could be equidistant to 100 nm so I presume that the "out of phase" explanation was an over simplification.  Not only that, even a sodium vapor lamp is not emitting photons that are all in step with one another, so in reality there a many out of phase photons travelling in each path in the experiment.  So how does the interferometer really work?  I have read that with a modern laser the reflecting mirrors can actually be at different distances, so maybe the assumption is that the beams both "keep time" the same, but return at different angles which is quite different that what I was taught in engineering school.  How would an interference pattern really be produced, and if relevant, had there had been an aether, would the returning beams have been expected to have the same wavelengths?

Comment: The modern explanation of "interference" says that each photon acts on its own and paths are determined by the EM field.   An excited electron/atom is generating many virtual forces long before the photon is emitted. Feynman's path integral basically says photons prefer path lengths of integer multiples of wavelength.

Comment: @PhysicsDave but did Michelson and Morley know that?

Comment: Yeah, mirrors are really smooth and have been since they existed. If a mirror was full of bumps comparable or bigger than the wavelength of light, it wouldn’t even be a mirror!

Comment: That said, there’s a difference between needing the mirror to not have local micron-size bumps, and having a giant mirror whose entire surface is flat to the micron level. The second is much harder, but not necessary.

Comment: As for the distance between the plates, that doesn’t need to be sub-micron precise either. It just needs to be not changing rapidly, i.e. at the micron level at the timescale that you make observations, as that would wash out the interference pattern. A constant offset is no problem.

Comment: @knzhou so again I was initially taught that the purpose was to find if the wavelength was still "in phase" at the target, but it seems to me it was more about detecting an aether wind that changed the angles of the light beams so that they weren't completely parallel to one another.

Comment: M&M probably had a few "interference" theories to work with and most importantly their own interpretations/beliefs. Fundamentally light "interferes" in multiples of its wavelength and that's all they really needed to know.  If there was an ether relative to the moving platform then maybe it could have been discovered by this method ... maybe not... but it would have been big news!

Comment: @PhysicsDave why wasn’t it important to make sure the mirrors were equidistant to within a fraction of the wavelength?  We were always taught that the beams travelled equal paths

Comment: I think your teachers were oversimplifying. There is absolutely no requirement that the arm lengths be exactly equal. The requirement is that the difference in the lengths is stable.

Comment: Michelson and Morley didn’t try to measure the absolute path length difference. They measured how the interference pattern _changed_ when they rotated the whole apparatus so that the ether wind would be coming from a different direction. A constant path length difference cancels out.

Comment: They can adjust the apparatus/mirrors with fine screw threads while at the same time observing patterns and then tighten it down. There are good videos on YouTube ... search "MIT laser".  The old videos are great, but the theory is classical, beware of the word "interference", it's abused and misunderstood.

Comment: @knzhou OK that makes sense.  So if they got certain distances between interference bands in one orientation and then let the apparatus rotate (I believe on a pool of mercury) the bands should get closer or farther if there is an aether wind.  In some orientations there might not be any interference.  That's most of the answer although I don't see why merely monochromatic light source would not just emit a lot of photons all out of step/phase with each other anyway.